# How to fix 404 error for a web service created with Apache CXF 3.3.5?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat9

For `http://localhost:8080`, Apache Tomcat home is working fine.But for `http://localhost:8080/WebServicesAssignment/services/ViduminiStorageServicePort` is shows 404 error.

[image: error message]

I tried to solve this issue by changing tomcat server location, adding index pages. But anything didn't work.

I'm using,

- Apache CXF 3.3.5
- Apache Tomcat 9.0
- jre 1.8.0
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developer 2019-12

Comment: Where and how did you deploy your application? Also, check your logs and post your webapp's name, web.xml excerpt - in short: Best to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @OlafKock
First, thank you for your feedback. I will try to provide details as you ask.